# App Store Submission: No Identities

Tags: ios, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No identities were available - administrator request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215530/no-identities-were-available-administrator-request)

OK I was going to post an image but SO won't let me.  It's an error box with a yellow triangle exclamation mark and the text "No Identities were Available, An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded, [Button] Download Identities... [Button] Import Develop Profile..."

Has anyone got any idea what is going on with this error?  Appears on clicking "validate" in the organiser after building for Archiving in the "Release" configuration. The Developer Profile is installed (I have re-downloaded and re-installed it heaps of times to try and get past this...).  The app exists in iTunes Connect and I have created an App ID for it in Dev Center, and provisioning profiles, etc.  It builds and runs fine....

I can't make head or tail of the help articles on the Developer Portal as they seem to be for some old version of Xcode and I have only ever really used version 4.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Oh, "Download Identities" does nothing either, it just shows a spinner for a while and redisplays the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:  App IDs are case sensitive, and must match between the App ID in the Developer Portal and the App ID in Xcode.  Exactly.

Answer (score 23):

I just had this same issue.  For me the solution was that I had made provisioning profiles in Member Center, but they were for Development rather than Distribution.  As soon as I made a Distribution profile (on a separate tab in the Provisioning Portal), I was good to go.

I hope that helps!

Comment: This wasn't the answer to my problem this time, but it IS a a valid and useful answer so I am up voting it.  I also got stuck at this part of the process for a while!

Comment: This worked for me with a slight modification: After making a distribution profile as you describe I had to reload them in Xcode | Preferences | Accounts | <account> | View Details | reload (icon). Otherwise Organizer | Validate remained ignorant of them (even after restarting Xcode).

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the **Distribution mobileprovision** file. Get your admin (or login as admin) to create and download one for your app from iOS Provisioning Portal - Provisioning - Distribution.

**Update:**
Here's "[About App Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)" instructions by Apple. Not duplicated here, since Apple keeps updating their system and a link to Apple's docs is more likely to remain uptodate.