# Xcode 4.3.2: "No identities were available" - Where to request a Dev Identity?

Tags: xcode, download, request, identity

Hey I have a problem with the validation and upload of apps to the app store with the new version of Xcode (4.3.**2**)

I installed the new version and now can not longer submit and validate apps.

I only see the following screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTpvT.jpg

Can someone tell me WHERE in the dev center ore in iTunes connect I can request an identity?

THX a lot
Laurenz from Germany

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643057/app-store-submission-no-identities and http://www.osxentwicklerforum.de/index.php?page=Thread&postID=181629 HTH

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. This is how I fixed it:

1. Login to the [iOS dev center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
2. Click "iOS Provisioning Portal" on the right
3. Click "Provisioning" on the left
4. Click "Distribution" tab at the top
   (You should see your distribution profile. If there is nothing there, then you have a problem and will need to create one.)
5. Click download next to the profile
6. Open the downloaded file with Xcode.
7. You're done!

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I've done the above, except I had to create a distribution profile because there wasn't any. Well, I guess at least all the bugs in Xcode keep me from being bored...

Comment: @houbysoft Speak for yourself. My life would be considerably less boring without xcode-isms.