# No identities were available - administrator request not solved by previous answers

Tags: ios, xcode, submit

I get the "No identities were available - administrator request" issue
I have a valid certificate, a match boundle ID, a valid provisioning profile (distribution) I have two apps, both I published 3 weeks ago to the app store with the configuration I currently have.

the only thing that changed is that I upgrade my mac to 10.9 and my xcode to 5, but left my device at IOS6
now both my apps failed to validate with the above error.

I tried the steps in many other articles like [No identities were available - administrator request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215530/no-identities-were-available-administrator-request)

or [Xcode 4.3.2: "No identities were available" - Where to request a Dev Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924090/xcode-4-3-2-no-identities-were-available-where-to-request-a-dev-identity)

or https://discussions.apple.com/message/21603155#21603155

and others 
nothing works

any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I spent two days reading forums and searching the web and finally figured out the problem.  Under your IOS provisioning profiles, you have to have a profile that is listed as ditribution under type.  It also needs to be listed under your account in xcode (xcode>preferences>account>view details) if it is not listed there, click the refresh button to have it check itunes connect for your certificate.  I tried deleting every certificate and everything from Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and let xcode create new certificates, but xcode says it will add distribution stuff and doesn't.  Make sure to use your provisioning profile that is a distribution type for your provisioning profile under your code signing in both of the app target build setting and the app project build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into Applications -> Utilities -> Keychains on my Mac and remove expired certificates. After removing those, I had to generate new certificates through the IOS Developer Site and import those into the Keychains application. After doing so, return to Xcode and in Build Settings, verify you are using the new Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile. (You will need both recreated, as revoking the Identity will invalidate the Provisioning Profile.)