# No identities were available - administrator request

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate

I had problems while "archiving" my app. I think there are invalid profiles because of iPhone Update to 5.1 and XCode update to 4.2.2.

I've taken now more than 4 hours to get rid of certification issues while using this thread step by step 3 times (which costs a lot of time):

[Getting "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714517/a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-found-in-your-ke)

I still have the following fault:
[image: XCode certification error]

No identities were available
An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded.

The "Download identities" button went back to this window after processing some seconds.

Do you know how to get out of this wood of certification documentations and solve that fault?

Comment: I've checked for case sensitivity and could not find any problems. I've recreated all today with ID of "master" which should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643057/app-store-submission-no-identities did not help in my case

Comment: Could someone update this for XCode 5.  Every single solution on here does NOT work in any way shape or form anymore.  Apple blew everything out of the water.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

1. Visit [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)
2. Go to **"iOS Provisioning Portal"** -> **"Certificates"** (Left sidebar) >> **"Distribution"** tab
3. Check field **"Provisioning Profiles"**. If empty, next (4)
4. Go to **"Provisioning"** (Left sidebar) -> **"Distribution"** tab. Press "New Profile" and complete it. 
   Go back to (3) check the field again.
5. Download and **"run"** (double click) the new provisioning profile.
6. In your project's build settings select the NEW provisioning profile (it might have the same name as the old one)
7. In your project's build settings update your code signing identities (all of them) to the new one if there is one. (The old one was probably expired which is one of the biggest causes for the error message you saw)
8. Verify that your bundle ID is correct (CaSe SeNsEtIvE)
9. Back to XCode Organizer - Devices. Click TEAM (Left sidebar) and click "Refresh" (right-bottom). You will find XCode fetch the new profile. If new content loaded, repeat steps 6 and 7 (they will have been changed!) 
   *If you can't find team because you are running a newer version of xCode, go to Xcode preferences (clicking "Xcode" on the mac toolbar on the top left corner of your screen) and go to account, select your team and click refresh. If new content loaded, repeat steps 6 and 7 (they will have been changed!)
   If you are in **Preferences** -> **Accounts** and you *still* can't refresh, then:

   - Click on the Accounts tab
   - Select an Apple ID in the list
   - Click "View Details" on the bottom right
   - Click on the refresh arrow on the bottom left
   - Xcode will now refresh the updated credentials, and you can proceed to validate or distribute your app.
10. Validate or distribute your app again. It should work.
11. If this didn't work then go to "TEAM" under project settings > targets and select "none"... Now that you have selected None you will need to repeat step 7 and change the code signing identities (all of them) and try archiving again.
12. Lastly, if none of the above worked. Simply create a new production certificate AND create a new provisioning profile with the same bundle ID. (Yes, this will work if you are updating an app that is already live). Download the cert and prov. profile and run both (double click). Now repeat step 6 and archive. This should work.

Comment: additional in XCODE the selection is needed to do in project where the provisioning item needs to be selected. thanks for your help.

Comment: I was still getting this error even though everything looked fine UNTIL I pressed Refresh in step 5. Then it was sorted....

Comment: @Takol and what if there is no "TEAM" (left sidebar) or "Refresh" (bottom-right) button???

Comment: @stephen Edited solution to that in for you!

Comment: **Important:** You can't validate with only an ad-hoc distribution.  You'll (also) need one for the App Store.

Comment: Brian White is right. But this response is quite right in normal error cases.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this answer. Could you go a bit more in depth in every step? I followed every step and I am still getting the exact same error as the question provided above.

Answer (score 17):

@Takoi's answer is correct. However, with my latest version of Xcode, there is no TEAM option in the Devices section of the Organizer. I had to do the following instead to refresh the credentials:

1. Go to Xcode->Preferences
2. Click on the Accounts tab
3. Select an Apple ID in the list
4. Click "View Details" on the bottom right
5. Click on the refresh arrow on the bottom left

Xcode will now refresh the updated credentials, and you can proceed to validate or distribute your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ugh, went through about 100 SO posts and this solved my issue. WHY DOESN'T APPLE AUTO REFRESH!

Comment: Oh, gosh! That was a solution what I was waiting about hour. Thanks.

Comment: I still get the same exact error as the question states.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the bundle id in your .plist file in XCode is the same as the bundle id in itunesconnect, if it's off, it won't be able to match the archive to the profile on itunesconnect when validating/distributing.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little easier now.

1. You go to the app [itunesconnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and login
2. click "certificates"
3. Provisioning Profiles / Distribution
4. generate a profile,
5. download the profile
6. double click it

Comment: This solved my problem in XCode 5. Although I think it should be [linkg](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/), 2. is "Provisioning Profiles" and you have to create a profile for **App Store** Distribution. I only created one for **Ad Hoc** (Testflight) and the error kept showing up until I created another for the App Store.

Comment: There are no certificates in itunesconnect

Comment: There is no 'certificates' link in itunesConnect. :(

Answer (score 3):

I am a member of 2 teams and had the same problem while uploading one of the projects.
Changing **General -> Identity -> Team** to **None** in project settings (XCode 5) allowed me to upload the application to iTunesConnect.

[Screenshot is here](http://codewithchris.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/img/XCode_5_ProjectSettings.png)

Comment: There is no Identity in General settings in Xcode! What to do?

Comment: @Dvole, It's not XCode General settings, but Project settings. See the screenshot in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

My certificate had expired which resulted in my provisioning profile being expired.
Once I -

- Updated my certificate on the iOS web portal
- Clicked Edited on the provision profile
- Selected the new certificate and clicked generate
- In Xcode I refreshed my provisioning profiles

Error went away

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is written somewhere in the stream, I did not read all in detail. I just want to emphasise on this point:

Due to an annoying xCode behavior, once you've set up everything, **you HAVE TO clean the project and Quit xCode**.

Then relaunch and build. Now you know if it works or not.

Comment: Still observing this issue with xCode 6.1, one year later.
In some cases, when you reload your developer certificates, you also may have to restart your mac. Perhaps due to Keychain cache.

Just to say if you think everything is correctly set, but nothing works, Reset all!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're going to have to request another developer cert. Go to the iOS dev center website and go to the provisioning portal. Click the certificates tab and follow the directions. https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

To be clear, you're problem doesnt seem to be provisioning related, it's specifically the developer cert. if you do get another cert, you'll have to create all new profiles to sign your apps with.

Comment: what is this, there are ways of fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

My bundle identifier was named differently. I had to change it from Nyquist.GasBro to com.Nyquist.GasBro which is what I had in the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

None of previous answers helped me, so I post my issue.

1. Dev Center: [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action?type=production) > Provisioning Profile > Distribution

Make sure that there is a distribution provisioning profile, and App ID in it is exactly the same as Bundle ID of your app in Xcode (Project Settings > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier).

2. Xcode: Project Settings > Build Settings > Code Signing:

   - Provisioning profile - choose that Distribution provisioning profile name (not Development!)
   - Code Signing Identity - I choosed Automatic since I have only one.

P.S. Before doing this, I deleted all unused and expired provisioning profiles and signing identities from Dev Center and from Xcode. Then, refreshed as mentioned in other answers: Xcode: Preferences > Accounts > (my Apple ID) > View Details > Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you are looking for is that when you generate the certificate request for COMMON NAME you need to put your HUMAN NAME as in John Smith, not your app name.  Apple uses this term Common Name in 2 different ways and doesn't tell you that the certificate is supposed to have your name on it whereas in another area they ask for common name and want the APP name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Nothing mentioned on this page did not work for me until i was deleted everything from archive. 
After that problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

For those who says that the Ad Hoc Distribution profile wont work this year 2014, I have to agree.

In Build Settings locate the Code Signing setting: for Release choose your Store Distribution and then select Menu>Product>Archive.

Later, in the Organizer Window, select your archive and clic in Validate. It will let you select the Ad Hoc profile and validate... then select Distribute, it will let you save as .ipa file.