# Unable to sign an app for distribution into app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to distribute an app into the app store, but I'm an able to sign it.

[image]

As you can see I do have access to our Distribution certificate:

[image: As you can see I do have access to our Distribution certificate]

I have tried both `Download Identities` and `Import Developer Profile`, neither with any success. I really have no idea what else to try; this question didn't address my issue [No identities were available - administrator request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215530/no-identities-were-available-administrator-request)

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: When I build for archiving, I do get this error, for what it's worth:

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

UPDATE: I found the issue, the bundle identifier had the wrong name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap things up here, the problem in this case was actually that I had the wrong bundle identifier entered in. Pretty frustrating that Xcode couldn't tell me this; I just happened to try out Application Uploader and that DID tell me that when it failed.

Comment: I will, but I'm unable to accept mine yet; which is technically the one that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

ok so this is what you need to do:

- login into Provisioning Portal
- go to Provisioning
- Distribution
- if you don't have a profile for your game..make one
- if you do..then download it and install it on your mac
- in your project:

  [image: in your poject]