# 3 Hours & Can't Create/Upload APP to iTunes - no identities were available

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Ok i've read a dozen posts and followed all the different advice given, but none of them have solved the problem in that when I trying to distribute my app via the organizer/archive I get: no identities were available

I have deleted my certificates in developer center, created a new developer/development certificate, refreshed the team in the organizer (all my old certificates seem to still show up) and tried to use the login doen't work, tried downloading the file and uploaded it via the tool and it doesn't work.

I'm completely lost, if there is someone here that can help I more then happy to pay you for a beer or two via paypal, we can chat here or on skype.

Just frustrated as hell as hoenstly building the app was less confusing/hard then trying to simply upload it into the app store...

Here are screen shots of my account on itunes connect and the point where I getting stuck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you delete your profiles too?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11230464/673492 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, creating certifacated in the wrong area... 3 hours and all I had to do is read the instructions better...

Comment: Haha. Lol, this was quite funny to read. +1 for developer humor :)