# Ios Distribution and validation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate

[image]

I get this error when trying to validate, now theres tons of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215530/no-identities-were-available-administrator-request), the problem is, none of their solutions have worked.

[image]

The top highlighted one is my distribution provisioning file thats associated with the project in question.

[image]

you can even see it's online.

so I have the profile, I have the app ready for uploading (how do you change the date for when it can be available on the app store **AFTER** you have said "yes these details are right, now lets get ready to upload?").

But I can't validate. every time I log in to "validate" I get that error. I have all the profiles required I have tripple checked every thing, but being **VERY NEW** to IOS dev, I am sure I missed some crucial step.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Have you created a Distribution Certificate and downloaded it?
2) Have you created App Store provisioning profile?
3) Are the code signing identities have been properly setup in your project?

If yes to the above then try manually downloading the provisioning profile from the developer portal and restarting XCode.

Comment: I always miss one of the steps the first time I set up a project for distribution. Glad that worked.